# Why is a secret organization creating truly anonymous people online?

Tags: technology, internet

What is the motivation for a secret organization to begin, as of 2017, taking babies and to make sure that they never log on to the Internet?  Such a person would be basically a totally anonymous quantity so that when they finally do go online, they would have no history whatsoever.  Presumably such a person would be very valuable, since their existence would be a complete surprise to anyone doing surveillance on the Internet.  However...what **are** they doing online in the first place? What would the secret organization want to gain from its anonymous operatives?

Comment: How would these "anonymous people" be more useful than just creating a fake persona, in your scenario?

Comment: That's a good question.  In my idea, the secret society goes to extreme lengths to ensure that there can be no tracing of its operatives.  For instance, they set up a network of domain name servers through which their operatives can access the Internet without being tracked whatsoever. I also imagine that this network is constantly being created and destroyed. If an operative is caught, though, they need to be able to be 100% useless.  I think, anyway, open to discussion

Comment: How exactly are those people anonymous? Don't they have birth certificates, are they not recorded in the identity databases of their countries, don't they attend school? In most literature dedicated to such issues, what those secret organizations want to do is the exact opposite: create an indentity (called a "legend" in the jargon) which does not correspond to a real person and can be assigned to an operative when needed. The better documented a legend is, the better history it has, birth certificate, school certificates, driving license, credit history, the more valuable it is.

Comment: Are you asking for the world's most expensive fake facebook profile? I do not think I get what you are asking. Could you clean up your question a bit? For example, you are answering the question from the title in line 2 already yourself. Also, unless you have very few humans, nobody would know all the people on the internet and be surprised by someone new there

Comment: I am fairly certain there are places in the world where you can go, right now, and find as many of these people as you would care to hire.

Comment: @Will: that's a great point.  I guess my organization can just go to a country that doesn't have a high percentage of Internet users.  Neat, and less sinister.   But still...why would I want such anonymity?

Comment: I suppose a better wording is this: I can imagine a world in which *I* want to be anonymous - I wouldn't get spammed, I might be into doing something illegal and don't want to get caught etc.  But why does *an organization* need anonymous operatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be useful, the anonymity would have to extend beyond just internet databases.   These phantoms would also need to be absent from every government database and the video feed archives of every security camera on the planet.

The tough part would be making them genetically anonymous, such that their DNA can only be used to determine their nationality, not their relatives.  The easiest way to do this is to choose the only children of parents who were also both only children going back several generations.  Then either kill the operatives' parents or keep them in this virginal anonymous state until their parents die naturally.

Now you have a person who can step out from a crowd and perform a deplorable act with no negative consequences for the agency.  They can perform assassinations, terrorist attacks and political kidnappings, and when they are finished, a time-release poison can silence them, leaving no physical method for tracking them back to their masters.

All this might be considered a good investment for a super secret agency, but as @Will said in the comments, people with zero internet and government database footprints are readily available in most of the impoverished countries of the world.

Still a long-sighted agency might start preparing these deliberate phantoms today in preparation (several generations from now) when no humans remain with naturally occurring digital anonymity.

Answer (score 5):

After your comment, I think I understand your question now.

There is one issue:
"as of 2017"

Let's look at the situation in 2017:

We have 8 billion people. A human live is basically worth nothing, raising a kid is still expensive.

We have the ability to program scripts that "live" on the internet that do the same thing, even better: They behave exactly as told (programmed) - always. This happens a lot.

We have globalized media. If the plans of the organization get public, they will face a lot of problems. This is a lot of risk to take.

Long story short: There isn't a reason why anyone would do that unless, well, they are willing to take a gigantic risk. You would be speculating that things will change drastically. Things that they might speculate on:

a) Someone plans to kill a lot of humans (for example to save the environment) and the organization knows that.

b) The secret organization has reason to believe that within the next 20 years, anonymity will stop existing. This means that all governments on earth will work together to implement a plan to get everyone online and into some data base.

c) The humiliating myspace-zombie-profile hypothesis: Some say people will not vote for a politician that has uploaded pictures of him/her drinking or similar things. An ultra-conservative organization might want to raise the next leader to be internet-free and would most likely use their own children. But we are getting into d) territory here (see d)).

And always, d) People in that secret organization are crazy. Some rich guy with paranoia wants to create something for no rational reason.